# How to correctly override qscintilla mousePressEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscintilla

I have class MainWindow and it have qscintilla editor, i want to add listener to editor mousePressEvent

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, gui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.editor.mousePressEvent = self.on_editor_click

    def on_editor_click(self, QMouseEvent):
        // here i want add my code
        return QsciScintilla.mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent)
```

If i override mousePressEvent - editor will broke (mouse clicks will not work). I tried call initial mousePressEvent, but it dont work, app crashing

Comment: `QsciScintilla.mousePressEvent(self.editor, QMouseEvent)`

Comment: thanks, i tested it, it crashing

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the mousePressEvent method to another function is not correct, mousePressEvent is not a signal, it is a function that is part of QsciScintilla.
A possible solution is that you create a personalized QsciScintilla that emits a signal created as shown below:

```
class ClickQsciScintilla(QsciScintilla):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
        QsciScintilla.mousePressEvent(self, event)
```

Then you create an instance of ClickQsciScintilla and connect to that signal:

```
self.__editor = ClickQsciScintilla()
self.__editor.clicked.connect(self.on_editor_click)
```

Your handler:

```
 def on_editor_click(self):
        print "Editor was clicked!"
```